# getting content of variables

Tags: php

I am trying to learn PHP and stumbled across this problem of having bad keys in my array 
i have this function

```
public function pdf_read_root()
{   
    $this->root = $this->pdf_resolve_object( $this->c, $this->pdf_find_root());

}
```

but `$this->root` is returning the wrong values, how do i get the individual contents, `$this->c & $this->pdf_find_root` to see what is being used in `pdf_resolve_object`

Comment: Could you define "wrong values"?

Comment: the keys that I am wanting are wrong, and thus does not succeed when i do an check like this $this->root[1][1]['/Pages']

Comment: Call print_r() around any variable to see what's inside, whether it be an object or array. It can help you debug what you might think is wrong.

Comment: What's the thing that screams WRONG in this code ? `$this->pdf_resolve_object( $this->c, $this->pdf_find_root());` +1 to the right answer!

Comment: "the keys that I am wanting are wrong" still doesn't give any more information. What are they? What do you expect them to be?

Comment: please answer the question and i will give you +1, i would like to know what is wrong

Answer (score 3):

```
public function pdf_read_root()
{   

    $this->root = $this->pdf_resolve_object( $this->c, $this->pdf_find_root());
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "<br> Value of member variable c is: ". print_r($this->c, true);
    echo "<br> Value of method pdf_find_root() is: ". print_r($this->pdf_find_root(),true);
    echo "<br> Value of member variable root is: ". print_r($this->root, true);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

Comment: This looks like a suggestion for debugging rather than an answer.